# Arraylist gets same values for all rows in all array positions

Tags: java, spring-mvc, arraylist

Arraylist gets values from database. its fine. but after completing 3 loops(3 records in database) finally arraylist should contain all 3 rows containing 2 columns in each. **Arraylist gets 3 rows but all column values are same.**

i got this

```
Arraylist [0] email : abc@gmail.com pwd : abc123
          [1] email : abc@gmail.com pwd : abc123
          [2] email : abc@gmail.com pwd : abc123
```

it want this

```
Arraylist [0] email : abc@gmail.com pwd : oih123
          [1] email : iii@yahoo.com pwd : nbh435
          [2] email : nbh@mail.in pwd : www123
```

**Controller**

```
arraylist = new ArrayList();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        try {

            modelclass obj = new modelclass();
            SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
            dataSource = new dbconnection.connection().getConnection(dataSource);
            JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info";
            srs = jt.queryForRowSet(sql);

            while (srs.next()) {
                 obj.setEmailid(srs.getString("email_id"));
                obj.setPwd(srs.getString("pwd"));
                arraylist.add(obj);  //i++;
            }
            model.addObject("arraylist", arraylist);
 return model;
```

**list.jsp**

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${arraylist}" var="key">
            <tr>
               <td>${key.email_id}</td>
               <td>${key.pwd}</td> 
            </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: well, you are working on the same instance of `modelclass` all the time. you need to create a new one after each iteration.

Comment: please help me with code.. i am new in Spring

Comment: that is basic java, nothing to do with `Spring`.

Comment: and .. take the model.addobject()  later. first take arraylist.add(obj).  first help me with this.

Comment: You only have *one* instance of `obj`, so you add the *same* object many times to the list, and the `setPwd` method keeps overriding the value, leaving the object with the last value set. Move the `modelclass obj = new modelclass();` line inside the loop. Also, please rename class to start with uppercase letter, as indicated by Java naming convensions.

Comment: thnkss .. it wokrd ...

Comment: ok.. now i am returning model to list.jsp page. i want to display all the records on that page. i am modifying the controller class code ... check the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Object as below.

```
       try {

        modelclass obj;
         /*Some Text*/

        while (srs.next()) {
           obj= new modelclass();

             obj.setEmailid(srs.getString("email_id"));
            obj.setPwd(srs.getString("pwd"));
            arraylist.add(obj);  //i++;
        }
        model.addObject("arraylist", arraylist);
```

Comment: ok.. now i am returning model to list.jsp page. i want to display all the records on that page. i am modifying the controller class code ... check the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have imported this piece of code